# oauth: Open access to anyone with the Access token

Tags: security, design-patterns, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am setting up OAUTH2 for my web application. Imagine the case, an entity ABC was authenticated and received an access token from my web application.

Is it necessary to ensure that the subsequent requests containing this access token from the entity ABC are indeed coming in from the entity ABC by having extra validation fields that only ABC is aware of.

OR, Should I grant access to anyone with this access token no matter who they are, believing that anyone who has this access token is indeed the entity ABC? 
 As it's my responsibility to secure the access token transmission to the entity ABC

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bearer scheme authentication, you grant access to anyone in possession of a valid access token. No additional info required.

See also:http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html

Answer (score 0):

The current OAuth 2.0 specifications have standardized the usage of so-called "bearer" access tokens that grant access to any client that presents a valid access token as @user18044 describes.

There is work in progress on standardizing an OAuth 2.0 extension that would require the client to proof that it the rightful owner of the access token along with presenting it, the so-called Proof-of-Possession draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-jones-oauth-proof-of-possession

That could be useful in environments that require a very high level of security, at the cost of a more complicated implementation. In most environments it would be enough to make sure that the access token is only ever passed over HTTPs to prevent it from leaking, so the current Bearer scheme would be sufficient.